# how to update the etcd member list

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

my cluster have 3 master node, now I have shutdown 1 master node, then I check the member from etcd database:

```
[root@fat001 bin]# ETCDCTL_API=3 /opt/k8s/bin/etcdctl member list
56298c42af788da7, started, azshara-k8s02, https://172.19.104.230:2380, https://172.19.104.230:2379
5ab2d0e431f00a20, started, azshara-k8s01, https://172.19.104.231:2380, https://172.19.104.231:2379
84c70bf96ccff30f, started, azshara-k8s03, https://172.19.150.82:2380, https://172.19.150.82:2379
```

still show 3 nodes started. why the etcd did not refresh the node status? what should I do to update the etcd status to the latest? is it possible to refresh the status manually? the kubernetes version is `1.15.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a node that was in a cluster, you should manually delete it from the etcd also i.e. by doing **'etcdctl member remove 84c70bf96ccff30f '.**

Make sure that etcd container is no longer running on the failed node, and that the node does not contain any data anymore:

```
rm -rf /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml /var/lib/etcd/

crictl rm "$CONTAINER_ID"
```

The commands above will remove the static-pod for etcd and data-directory /var/lib/etcd on the node.Of course, you can also use the **kubeadm reset** command as an alternative. However, it also will remove all Kubernetes-related resources and certificates from this node.